# Get category ID after wp_insert_term

Tags: terms

I'm using `wp_insert_term` to create categories, after the category is created I'd like to get its ID:

`$cat_id = wp_insert_term($name, 'category',    array('slug' => $slug) );`

...however when I try to print `$cat_id` I get `Array` instead of the actual ID. I guess I have to state which part of the array I need, but I don't really know what the variable for the ID would be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be a key of `term_id`, so `echo` out `$cat_id['term_id']` and you should get the new terms ID.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term#Return_Values):

> Return Values (array|WP_Error)
>
> The Term ID and Term Taxonomy ID.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> array( 'term_id'=>12,'term_taxonomy_id'=>34)
> ```

So try for example:

```
$cid = wp_insert_term( $name, 'category', array( 'slug' => $slug ) );

if ( ! is_wp_error( $cid ) )
{
    // Get term_id, set default as 0 if not set
    $cat_id = isset( $cid['term_id'] ) ? $cid['term_id'] : 0;
    // ... etc ...
}
else
{
     // Trouble in Paradise:
     echo $cid->get_error_message();
}
```